# Wordpress Renovation Copmany Theme google map error - Mising API key

Tags: php, wordpress, api, google-maps, themes

I can't solve Google map missing API key. I can't find where to change it.

Here is my website: http://biogra.lt/en/contact/.

The theme im using is Renovation Compony: https://themeforest.net/item/renovation-company-construction-and-building-wordpress-theme/14835524

Thank you.

Comment: add more efforts you have put to make it work.

Comment: this is a commercial theme where the author provide limited support. try asking him. he knows his own theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API Key is actually located inside the URL for the Google Maps api. Near the bottom of your source you have this line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDbBlb-UYr7APyNHb40lYnGbwm8rp6LRFw&#038;callback=initMap&#038;ver=4.5.3'></script>
```

Insert your new key in place of the old one.